# Openshift case insensitive Route

Tags: openshift

i am new to Openshift Container Platform. Is there a way to create a route with a case insensitive path?

Currently my route is only listening to the exact path e.g. foo.com/test works but foo.com/tEsT does not.

```
kind: Route
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
spec:
  host: foo.com
  path: /test
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: test-service
```